# Demonstrating that a non-constant holomorphic function attains its maximum on the boundary of its region?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing the disc $|z| \leq 1$. Suppose that $f$ has a simple zero at $z = 0$ and vanishes nowhere else in $|z| \leq 1$. Let

$$f_{\epsilon}(z) = f(z) + \epsilon g(z)$$

Show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then $f_{\epsilon}(z)$ has a unique zero in $|z| \leq 1$.

Rouche's theorem states that if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in an open set containing a circle $C$ and its interior, and if $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$ for all $z \in C$, then $f$ and $f + g$ have the same number of zeroes inside $C$.

I want to show that $|f(z)| > |\epsilon g(z)|$. Then $f(z) = \epsilon g(z)$ and $f_{\epsilon}(z)$ have the same number of zeroes in $C$ (i.e. one zero), and I'm done.

But how do I show that $|f(z)| > |\epsilon g(z)|$? Assuming $g(z)$ is not the constant $0$ function, a solution I've seen says that $|f(z)|$ and $|g(z)|$ attain maxima $M_f$ and $M_g$ respectively on $|z| = 1$. How precisely is this true?

I'm aware of the maximum modulus principle, which states that if $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function in a region $\Omega$, then $f$ cannot attain a maximum in $\Omega$. Can I alter this definition in some way to conclude that if $f$ is a non-constant holomorphic function, $f$ achieves its maximum on the boundary of the region? Is it as simple as saying that since it cannot attain a maximum *inside* of $\Omega$, it has to obtain a maximum on $\Omega$'s boundary? How come the function can't just stretch all the way to $\infty$ inside the region? -- why must it attain a maximum on the boundary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it's possible for a function that is holomorphic on an open domain $\Omega$ to have a pole on the boundary $\partial \Omega$, as you suggest. For instance, $(z-1)^{-1}$ is holomorphic on the open unit disk but goes to $\infty$ at $z = 1$.

But recall the assumption from the very beginning: $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic in a region containing the *closed* unit disk $\{|z| \leq 1\}$. In particular, they are continuous on the closed disk and therefore obtain a maximum modulus somewhere on the closed disk. The maximum modulus principle ensures that can't occur in the interior (provided they are not constant), so it must be on the boundary.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks -- however, why precisely does $f$ and $g$ being continuous on the closed disk guarantee they obtain a maximum modulus somewhere on the closed disk?

Comment: The extreme value theorem: a continuous function from a compact set to $\mathbb R$ attains a minimum and a maximum (more generally speaking, the continuous image of a compact space must be compact; in $\mathbb R$ this means closed and bounded, which implies a min and a max). The closed unit disk is compact, so we have a maximum.

Comment: Note that an important point in this question is that $|f(z)|$ also attains a non-zero minimum on the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m = \min_{|z| = 1} |f(z)|$, $M = \max_{|z| = 1} |g(z)|$. We have $m>0$.
Choose $\epsilon >0$ such that $\epsilon M < m$.

If $|z|=1$, then $|f_\epsilon(z)| = |f(z)+\epsilon g(z)| \ge |f(z)|-\epsilon |g(z)| \ge m-\epsilon M >0 $, so $f_\epsilon$ has no zeroes on the unit circle.

Furthermore, if $|z| = 1$, we have  $|f_\epsilon(z) - f(z)| = \epsilon |g(z)| \le \epsilon M < m \le |f(z)|$, hence by Rouchés theorem, $f_\epsilon$ and $f$ have the same number of zeros (and poles) in the open unit disk.